# FullCalendar V4 not rendering with IE11 Comptability Mode

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, fullcalendar, compatibility, addeventlistener

I am using FullCalendar version 4.  When my users launch the target page under IE11 the calendar does not render if they have the browser's Compatibility View setting checked.

I cannot reproduce this problem in my Development environment, perhaps because the users access their environment over their intranet.  Has anyone else seen or solved this problem?

I had a user check their console output. The problem seems to be that the method `document.addEventListener` is not available in compatibility mode. Is there another way of initializing FullCalendar version 4?

Answer (score -1):

I try to download the sample code from this link.

[FullCalendar v4 example link](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-scheduler/releases)

I host the sample on IIS to test the issue with IE 11.

Based on my testing result, I find that sample works fine without compatibility view mode.

If I add the site in compatibility view mode than it is not rendering the calendar and generates some errors in console.

[image]

Looks like compatibility mode use IE 7 mode and it is not compatible with FullCalender v4 version caused this issue.

Simple way to solve the issue is to turn off the compatibility view mode.

Comment: addEventListener is not specific to fullCalendar

Comment: @ADyson, Issue is that addEventListener supports from IE 9 but compatibility mode using IE 7 mode. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener Please check it before down voting.

Comment: i know that. But my point was that this is a broader issue than just compatibility with fullCalendar. I think your answer should highlight that the problem is really with addEventListener rather than anything specifically within fullCalendar's implementation. What you've written in your comment just above should be an important part of the answer, because that explains _why_ the problem happens. All your answer does above is verify that there's a problem.

Comment: Maybe you have misunderstanding. Issue is with compatibility mode. Many functionalities will not be available while using it. because IE 7 does not have it. Its not specifically with addEventListener. There may be many more which is not supported by IE 7.

Comment: I'm quite sure that there are many more things than just addEventListener. But your answer isn't even highlighting that specific thing, which is the one which is occurring in this scenario. So a better answer would highlight that one thing, and then go on to explain that there may be other issues as well. Basically, these comments you're addressing to me, should be part of the answer. That's really all I'm saying.